# Using external python with originpro package to plot 3d waterfall graph

Tags: python, tkinter, cross-domain, data-analysis, data-processing

I am quite new to python and I am trying to automate my data processing using python and originpro package to efficiently plot my data. I am using 3 graph templates to plot them. The first graph works beautifully but the Graph 2 and 3 are 3D waterfall and I am keep getting errors.

I think the main issue is to choose range of columns for y-axis and z-axis is the header name.

```
import originpro as op
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

# Very useful, especially during development, when you are
# liable to have a few uncaught exceptions.
# Ensures that the Origin instance gets shut down properly.
# Note: only applicable to external Python.
import sys


def origin_shutdown_exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    """Ensures Origin gets shut down if an uncaught exception"""
    op.exit()
    sys.__excepthook__(exctype, value, traceback)


sys.excepthook = origin_shutdown_exception_hook

# Only run if external Python
if op.oext:
    op.set_show(True)

# Prompt user to select an Origin template file for graph 1
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
template_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select Origin Template File for Graph 1", filetypes=[("Origin Template Files", "*.otpu")])

# Prompt user to select a CSV file for the selected template
csv_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title=f"Select CSV File for {os.path.basename(template_file_path)}", filetypes=[("CSV Files", "*.csv")])

# Prompt user for the output Origin file name
output_file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title="Save Output Origin File", filetypes=[("Origin Project Files", "*.opj")])

# Load the CSV file into Origin worksheet
wks = op.new_sheet()
wks.from_file(csv_file_path, False)

# Create a new graph using the selected template for graph 1
gr = op.new_graph(template=template_file_path)

# Add plot to the graph using the data from the worksheet
gr[0].add_plot(wks, 1, 0, type=230)
gr[0].rescale()

# Prompt user to select an Origin template file for graph 2
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
template_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select Origin Template File for Graph 2", filetypes=[("Origin Template Files", "*.otpu")])

# Prompt user to select an Excel file for the selected template for graph 2
excel_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title=f"Select Excel File for {os.path.basename(template_file_path)}", filetypes=[("Excel Files", "*.xlsx")])

# Create a new worksheet
wks = op.new_sheet()

# Load the Excel file into Origin worksheet for graph 2
wks.from_file(excel_file_path, True)  # Set the second parameter to True to specify that the first row contains column names

# Create a new graph using the selected template
gr = op.new_graph(template=template_file_path)

# Add plot to the graph using the data from the worksheet for graph 2
gr[0].add_plot(wks, x_col=1, y_col=list(range(12)), z_col=3, type=62)
gr[0].rescale()

# Prompt user to select an Origin template file for graph 3
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
template_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select Origin Template File for Graph 3", filetypes=[("Origin Template Files", "*.otpu")])

# Prompt user to select a CSV file for the selected template for graph 3
csv_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title=f"Select CSV File for {os.path.basename(template_file_path)}", filetypes=[("CSV Files", "*.csv")])

# Load the CSV file into Origin worksheet for graph 3
wks = op.new_sheet()
wks.from_file(csv_file_path, False)

# Create a new graph using the selected template for graph 3
gr = op.new_graph(template=template_file_path)

# Add plot to the graph using the data from the worksheet for graph 3
gr[0].add_plot(wks, x_col=1, y_col=list(range(12)), z_col=wks[0][0].column_index, type=62)
gr[0].rescale()

# Tile all windows
op.lt_exec('win-s T')

# Save the project to the specified output file path using both op.oext and op.save
if op.oext:
    op.save(output_file_path)
else:
    gr.save(output_file_path)
```

Not sure how to make the header file (Long-name in origin) to use as z-axis.[ideally it should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dfZE.png) and [the data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quzUY.png) . Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: OriginPro is a commercial product. Why not ask them? Anyway, I strongly recommend to use standard data science tools such as Matplotlib, Pandas, SciPy, etc.